# How to store unhashable objects

Tags: python

I'm using a library that provides me with some objects (SocketIO sessions, but that's a detail outside the scope of the question).

I want to store (the references to) those objects (not copies) upon connection and later remove them. Coming from a C++ background, I'd expect a `set` to be able to just store the pointers to those objects. But those are not hashable, so I can't put them in a `set`. And I don't know a Python way to get something akin to a pointer. I can put them in a list, but then the removal requires traversal (O(n)) and the insertion would allow duplicate.

Is there any trick to obtain something that behaves like a C++ pointer (comparable, ordered), from a Python object?

Right now, I'm doing:

```
# global var
my_objects = []

# upon receive:
my_objects.append(session)

# upon removal:
my_objects = my_objects - session
```

Comment: Are you sure these objects are unhashable? I don't know what library you're using, but a quick search in the repositories of a few likely candidates suggest that the objects you're working with probably hash by identity.

Comment: Try **OrderedDict** from **collections** module. Here is the link https://pymotw.com/2/collections/ordereddict.html.

Comment: @RishikeshAgrawani I tried it, `OrderedDict` can't store unhashable objects either.

Comment: Okay so you want **unhashable** object in Python? I read somewhere you tried **list** so I suggested.

Comment: Without going into detail, you need to learn a bit about the Python object model. In short, every reference (something that is attached to a variable name or temporary) behaves like a C++ `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks, I realize that (shared_ptr behaviour). My question was how to store/use such object for indexing. It seems id() is the part I was missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is to use the id of the object. It identifies the object, although it will only work if you're really using the same object and not a new one with the same values.

```
# global var
my_objects = {}

# upon receive:
my_objects[id(session)] = session

# upon removal:
del my_objects[id(session)]
```