# Dict or WeakKeyDictionary with identity equality -- wrap unhashable objects to check identity

Tags: python, weak-references

I want to use some objects as keys for some dict, which are either unhashable, or hashable but I want to overwrite their `__eq__`/`__hash__` with the default `object.__eq__`/`object.__hash__`, i.e. namely `a == b` iff `a is b`.

(These objects could e.g. be `numpy.ndarray`, `torch.Tensor`, or other things, but I want to ask in general now.)

E.g.:

```
x = numpy.array([2,3,4])
d = {x: 5}
```

That would give the exception `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`.

Or:

```
x = torch.Tensor([2,3,4])
d = weakref.WeakKeyDictionary()
d[x] = 5
print(d[x])
```

That would give the exception `RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous`. (Which is quite misleading or unexpected. But I assume this is because it will do `bool(__eq__(...))` internally. However, strangely, there is no such exception when I use a normal `dict` here. Why?)

I could write a custom object wrapper to solve this, like:

```
class WrappedObject:
  def __init__(self, orig):
    self.orig = orig
  
  def __eq__(self, other):
    return object.__eq__(self.orig, other.orig)

  def __ne__(self, other):
    return object.__ne__(self.orig, other.orig)

  def __hash__(self):
    return object.__hash__(self.orig)
```

That would solve the first case. Now I can write:

```
x = numpy.array([2,3,4])
d = {WrappedObject(x): 5}
print(d[WrappedObject(x)])  # 5
```

Is there sth like `WrappedObject` in some of the std lib?

The `id` function has similar behavior, although it just returns an `int`, and doesn't have a reference back to the original object. So for this example, I could write:

```
x = numpy.array([2,3,4])
d = {id(x): 5}
print(d[id(x)])  # 5
```

Note that this might be problematic! In case `x` gets freed later on, then another object could theoretically be created which has the same `id`, because `id` is only guaranteed to be unique during the lifetime, not after its lifetime.
(Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50994328/how-to-store-unhashable-objects), although the accepted answer exactly has this problem.)

This problem would not happen with `WrappedObject`, as the reference is always kept alive.

Is there sth which would wrap `dict` to automatically use sth like `WrappedObject` under the hood? I.e. specifically I want that for all the keys, it only uses their identity for equality.

Now consider my second case, specifically `WeakKeyDictionary`. I cannot use `WrappedObject`, because the `WrappedObject` itself is not kept alive, so all keys would immediately vanish:

```
x = torch.Tensor([2,3,4])
d = weakref.WeakKeyDictionary()
d[WrappedObject(x)] = 5
print(list(d.items()))  # prints []
```

The only real solution I currently see is to reimplement `WeakKeyDictionary` myself, using sth like `WrappedRefObject`. Is there a better solution? Does this already exist in the std lib or elsewhere?

Comment: Related:  https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/88306

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not too difficult to create a wrapper class using [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), though it might be more robust to create your own mapping class like the following (untested):

```py
import collections.abc
import weakref

class WeakKeyIdMap(collections.abc.MutableMapping):
    """Like weakref.WeakKeyDictionary except identity is used, not hash."""

    def __init__(self):
        self._values = {}
        self._keyrefs = {}

    def pop_id(self, idk):
        self._keyrefs.pop(idk)
        return self._values.pop(idk)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._values[id(key)]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        idk = id(key)
        if idk not in self._keyrefs:
            self._keyrefs[idk] = weakref.ref(key, lambda: self.pop_id(idk))
        self._values[idk] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        idk = id(key)
        self._keyrefs.pop(idk)
        del self._values[idk]

    def __iter__(self):
        for idk in self._values:  # Use self._values to preserve iteration order.
            key = self._keyrefs[idk]()
            if key is not None or key == id(None):
                yield key

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._values)
```